# How to run conjure-up after a reboot

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

Finally have conjure-up running with an openstack spell.
Openstack is working good so far.
Now what can I expect if I shut off my computer?
When I boot it back up - do I need to run conjure-up again in the same way?
(it took HOURS to finish)

Maybe when I reboot I won't even need to run conjure-up?
I searched all over to answer this question - was surprised I couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Rebooted and all is good - didn't need to "start" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed openstack you don't need to re-run conjure-up.  Conjure-up uses juju to do the install and if you want to add new resources you need to use juju to do it.